# Cannot debug program

Tags: debugging, pycharm

When i run my program everything seems to work fine bu when i debug i get this:

**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "", line 1006, in *find_and_load_unlocked   File
> "", line 688, in *load_unlocked   File
> "", line 883, in exec_module
>
> File "", line 241, in
> *call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\DimascanTEMP\modules\ExcelFind.py",
> line 2, in 
> import pandas as pd   File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\DimascanTEMP\Venv\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport_*feature**.py",
> line 142, in *import
> return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\DimascanTEMP\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init**.py",
> line 11, in 
> **import**(dependency)   File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\DimascanTEMP\Venv\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport_*feature**.py",
> line 142, in *import
> return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\DimascanTEMP\Venv\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init**.py",
> line 195, in 
> core.numerictypes.typeDict,   File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\DimascanTEMP\Venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init**.py",
> line 161, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError(f"Module {**name**!r} has no attribute {name!r}") AttributeError: Module 'numpy.core' has no attribute
> 'numerictypes'

**

I find different reasons online but none worked for me.

Any suggestions ?

Cheers, John

Comment: If you write a summary of what you tried, it will avoid us to repeat what you found online. Are you sure you are running inside the same environment? (and please: edit your question so we have a nicer stack trace, now it is almost unreadable).

Comment: Hi Giacomo,

I'm new here so sorry for the trace.

This the error:
AttributeError: Module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'

I tried reinstalling pandas and numpy and downgrading numpy.

I'm running Python 3.10 with Pycharm

Comment: Hi Giacomo,
I found something (by chance):

I changed the option "PyQt compatible" from "auto" to "PyQT5 " and the issue is gone.
Can i leave it like this ?

Cheers John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the option "PyQt compatible" from "auto" to "PyQT5 " and the issue is gone.